# Very large networks in tensorflow

Tags: memory, tensorflow, neural-network, gpu

I am trying to train a neural network in tensorflow, but my array of weights is sufficiently large that I am running into the 2GB GraphDef limit.  What is my best recourse in this situation?

Note: I am not *really* using the full functionality of tensorflow (e.g. my network has no optimizers).  Rather, I am just using tensorflow as a way to perform some basic array ops on the GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably accidentally initialising a tf.Variable with a large constant. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2382

Workaround from the github issue:

```
init_val = np.array(...)  # Construct a large numpy array.
init_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=init_val.shape)
v = tf.Variable(init_placeholder)
# ...
sess.run(v.initializer, feed_dict={init_placeholder: init_val})
```